# Import xml from multiple urls at the same time using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am wondering if it is possible to import multiple XML URLs data at the same time without having to repeat myself for each one of them.
The code that I have below, works fine and brings the desired data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xmlPB
CREATE TABLE #xml ( myXML XML )
GO

DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @URL = 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml' 

DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @XML xml
DECLARE @Obj int 
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 

INSERT #xml ( myXML )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT
```

If I rename the variables and add another URL (and repeat the same code), it does bring the data on a new row and that is what I am trying to avoid and keep the code as clean as possible.

Thanks in advance for your time and and advice.

Comment: The logical response is yes, if you create a second process or call the process a second time, it will run from a second instance (SPID). Is this a learning exercise? Why not try it to answer you're own question? Perhaps you could explain the goal or give a broader picture. To merge xml you have stored in a column with an xml page would take a different process

Comment: @Random_User Thank you for your response. No, this is something I was wondering about. Just a side practice. As I mentioned, I am able to get the the data and as you mentioned, the probable "best" case scenario would be to call another process and update the table instead. As far as merging the data, that is not what I am looking for at this time.

Comment: You might place all urls in a table and work this down with a `CURSOR` loop...

Comment: Storing different sources of xml into a single table is most likely what you would want to do, you don't want to have a mix bag of xml with different structures stored in the same record, its doubtful you'd be able to parse it. I think for now you should embrace it, you'll find later on, objectionably it should be this way. It seems you are trying to bend the spoon, only realize the truth of it, keep it separate. If the xml is of the same structure you can use xnodes() to parse it as a single(secondary) process.